# Issue while running Linux Command using Java?

Tags: java, linux

I am running command using Java and getting no output.

```
Process p;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();  
    String s1 = "queryData 1005017 --format '\"%s" scope'";

    System.out.println("Command is " + s1);


    try {  

        p = run.exec(s1);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
        p.getErrorStream();  
        p.waitFor();

    }
```

While the same command --->  queryData 1005017 --format '"%s" scope'  runs without any issue. Wondering am i missing any thing while handling  either double quote, or % sign?

Comment: Assuming that your missing backslash is just a typo (does your program compile?), have you tried checking `p.exitValue()` after the `waitFor` to see if it terminated successfully or not?

Comment: Yes that was typo. exit value i am getting is exit: 1

Comment: So, it exited unsuccessfully. Try reading the error stream instead of the input stream and see what kind of error it gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do NOT use strings to start processes from Java. Correct way is usage of [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
p = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(
    "queryData", "1005017", "--format", "\"%s\" scope")).start();
```

Comment: Thanks. That fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't escape the internal quotes properly:

```
String s1 = "queryData 1005017 --format '\"%s" scope'";
            ^--start java string             ^--end java string
                                               ^^^^^ what's this mean to java?
```

You probably want

```
String s1 = "queryData 1005017 --format '\"%s\" scope'";
                                             ^--note this
```

instead.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't compile, OP says it doesn't return output. Perhaps it's just a typo.