# Run a bat file in java

Tags: java, batch-file

im trying to run a bat file and it dosent do anything.
When i open the bat file manually by double clicking on it in Windows,
it opens a cmd windod that runs a CLI. 
The bat file needs to run jar.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void changeToCli() {

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Gleb\\workspace1\\MVP\\CLI\\RunMe.bat");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: Is any exception thrown?

Comment: Nope, it runs and does nothing.

Comment: If you call further batches from your batch file you might need to use cmd /c prefix. http://superuser.com/questions/712279/commands-run-in-a-batch-file-only-when-writing-cmd-c-before

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it's input, output and error streams correctly.

The batch file may be waiting for some input, or there might be output on the batch's output or error stream that's larger than the buffer, causing the batch to block until the output / error output is consumed.

Note that this means consuming the input (it's program's output, named input on the Java side) and error streams in two separate threads. See [Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console) for hint on how to avoid the need to handle that yourself.

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this is with [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--).

Answer (score 0):

(a) use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime, e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003191/2078908).

(b) bat file is a script, actually cmd.exe executes these files

```
cmd.exe /c path/to/your.bat
```

Comment: Still dosent do anything

Comment: Start with simple new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("cmd.exe", "/?")).start(); Then read process output stream.